# Unable to properly redirect after OAuth2 authentication using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to build a basic Spring Boot app that will allow me delegate the work of authenticating users to an external OAuth2 provider such as Facebook.

I've got two main issues:

1. Once the authentication process is complete, and I get:

> GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/me" resulted in 200 (OK)

I also get the following:

> Reading [interface java.util.Map] as "application/json" using
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@2a7ce52b]
>              Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@4f061f45
>              SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.

It is as if something is wrong with parsing and storing the returned credentials.

2. Sometimes I get a 401 error:

> Authentication request failed:
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException:
>   Could not obtain access token

It is a some sort of hit and miss, and I could not trace down the problem. It also happened when using Google OAuth2 instead.

I Basically used the @EnableOAuth2Sso annotation, and configured the credentials using the application.yml file:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: 123
      clientSecret: bla
      accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
      tokenName: oauth_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me
      preferTokenInfo: false
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have managed to solve this, the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` maven dependency has been marked as `<scope>provided</scope>`, thus interfering with the ability to properly intialize the spring context object in the embedded tomcat.